# owl-carousel - How to Slide By to 3rd slide using every next dot - .owl-dot:Active

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I want to slide by 3 so I used slideby:3 but it is sliding in Auto mode only.
When I am clicking sequentially one by one every dot (owl-dot) it is sliding by 1 slid instead of 3. So what property I can add in jquery or my style.css so that in both Autoplay and manual click on dot slide move with the same number of slides (3 slides).

### Here is my: jquery

```
Doller sign used ('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({

items:4,
margin:40,
loop:true,

nav:true,`enter code here`
navSpeed:200,

dots:true,
dotsEach:true,

autoplay:true,
autoplaySpeed: 200,

slideBy:3,
})
```

---

I am looking step by on dot, something like :

```
.owl-dot:Active {
slideBy:3;
}
```

I know that the above code won't work but just to express my question clearly I am giving an idea if there is there any property which I can write either in jquery or style.css. or (maybe click every may work for my situation but it is complex for me to understand and associate that code, I am new in jquery) 
It is very complex and not at all able to understand :

```
Doller sign used ('.own-carousel .dot').hover(function() {
        $(this).click();
        }, function() {});
```

Note : here what code I can write to perform slideBy:3 actions on click on a dot

One more thing I am looking at that is the number of dots under my slides. for example, I have 7 slides and I am stepping by 2 slides to land on 3rd slide but I want 6 dots so even after 2nd dot all slides have been scrolled (as at a time display is "items:4" /slide/one cycle) still from 3rd dot it starts as a loop constant (continue motion in one direction) rather (first reverse all and then start)

I am unable to find on the internet and carousel doc that is why I am posting here, so I need help in my code to achieve this functionality. (I saw same dot stepping by behavior on many websites) I also did chrome-->inspect feature to find what property other websites are using but unable to figure it out.

Note : I used Doller sign before every jquery as while posting this query I am unable to post when using a symbol of doller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to set the [dotsEach option](http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#dotseach) to 3.

Comment: Yes, thanks it solved my first problem but for the second problem which is  "I want more dots to appear, for example - for 5 slides 6 or 9 dots so that it appears that I have many clients." How this will happen, how can I increase the number of dots regardless number of stepping on every 3rd slide (regardless: 6 slides / 3 steps by = 2 dots, this I don't want rather I want 5 or 7 dots and on clicking each consecutive dot still it should step on 3rd slide) [currently on adding 'dotsEach:3 for my 6 slides I am getting only 2 dots only]

Comment: To do that, it seems you'll need to turn the dots option off and build a custom version. You can use the trigger method with `to.owl.carousel` to transition to the appropriate slide: http://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Comment: Although it might be possible to add extra dots after they've been generated and give them click handlers to triggers the click handlers of the Owl-generated ones.

Comment: First of all, I want to thank you for answering my question. I think an easy solution is adding the same images just after followed by the first unique sequence, also maintaining the same order to the next cycle, also considering at a time if 4 images are displayed on a  screen then next 3rd should be unique. This is a very easy way and I already did that.